# IE Edge transform problems

Tags: html, css, svg, microsoft-edge

What can i do to align the text inside the svg donut in the Edge Browser correctly. All other Browsers display it fine.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gopVwr

```
<figure class="vendor-donut">
          <div class="figure-content">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="donut" role="img" viewBox="0 0 42 42" width="100%" height="100%">
              <circle class="donut-ring" role="presentation" fill="transparent" stroke="#f00" stroke-width="3" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.9155" />
              <circle class="donut-segment" fill="transparent" stroke="#140" stroke-dasharray="100, 0" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-width="3" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.9155" />
              <g class="chart-text">
                <text class="chart-number" x="50%" y="50%">50</text>
                <text class="chart-label" x="50%" y="50%">out of 100</text>
              </g>
            </svg>
          </div>
        </figure>
```

CSS

```
.vendor-donut {width:400px}

.vendor-donut .chart-text {
  -moz-transform: translateY(0.25em);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0.25em);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0.25em);
  transform: translateY(0.25em);
}
.vendor-donut .chart-number {
  font-size: 0.6em;
  line-height: 1;
  text-anchor: middle;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-0.25em);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-0.25em);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.25em);
  transform: translateY(-0.25em);
}
.vendor-donut .chart-label {
  font-size: 0.2em;
  text-anchor: middle;
  -moz-transform: translateY(0.5em);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0.5em);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0.5em);
  transform: translateY(0.5em);
}
.vendor-donut .figure-content
{
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  align-self: center;
}
.vendor-donut .figure-content svg {
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: presentation attributes (height, width, align) are depreciated and should be in px, not %. replace the height and width attributes of the inline svg element with a style attribute style="width:100%" - should be enough...

Comment: @RobParsons where did you see that presentation attributes are being deprecated? They [seem still well alive](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/styling.html#PresentationAttributes). And the default values for `width` and `height` [are still `100%`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/geometry.html#Sizing), so why *should* they be in `px` when the default value is itself in `%`?

Comment: @kaido https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/presentational_elements_and_attributes

Comment: @RobParsons I don't think an article about html tells you much if anything about SVG.

Comment: no... its about html5... my solution works though doesn't it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="donut" role="img" viewBox="0 0 42 42" style="width:100%">
```